# How can I get the device phone number with Expo?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I want to know the phone number of the connected device.
I tried the expo-contacts and expo-device libraries, but I couldn't get the information I wanted. What should I do?

```
import * as Contacts from "expo-contacts";
import * as Device from "expo-device";

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await Contacts.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if (status === "granted") {
        const { data } = await Contacts.getContactsAsync({
          fields: [Contacts.Fields.PhoneNumbers],
        });

        if (data.length > 0) {
          const contact = data[0];
          console.log("contact", contact);
          
          console.log(Device);
        }
      }
    })();
  }, []);
```